# What is the best practice for indicating download, ping or target hyperlink types to assistive technology?

Tags: html, hyperlink, accessibility, screen-readers

Is there a best practice to indicate to assistive technology (such as screen readers) that hyperlinks are configured to do something other than redirecting the current page? (i.e. those that have `mailto`, `download`, `ping` or `target` attributes).

Example:

```
<a href="myfile.jpg" download="myfile.jpg">
    Some File 
    <span>10Kb / JPG</span>
</a>
```

will still be announced as "link" instead of "download".

Is this okay or is there a best way / best practice to differentiate 'ordinary' links from downloads, etc.?

Is there anything else I could do instead of an additional span for screen readers only that will explain the behaviour? For example:

```
<a href="myfile.jpg" download="myfile.jpg">
   <span class="sr-only">Download</span> 
   Some File 
   <span>10Kb / JPG</span>
</a>
```

Is this even a good way?

Comment: Maybe you can use popover, or simple way is create an element only visible when hovering over the link

Comment: My question is mosty about accessibility and screen reader support. An additional popover during mouseover/hover won't really solve this problem I guess.

Comment: How are you telling users who aren’t using screen readers that it will trigger a download instead of navigation? Why isn’t that good enough for screen reader users?

Comment: Emma's suggestion is likely to fall foul of WCAG SC 1.4.13 "Content on Hover".

Comment: I should point out that WCAG SC 1.3.1 says "Information, structure, and relationships conveyed through presentation can be programmatically determined or are available in text." - strictly speaking, the inclusion of the download attribute will meet the 'programmatically determined' criterion, and it is up to the AT vendors to do something useful with it. You can (as others have suggested) introduce a small text affordance to the accessible name for the link. BTW, this topic is being discussed by the ARIA community https://github.com/w3c/aria/issues/482